# Is it possible to use Alexa Voice Profile in my custom skill

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Is it possible to use Alexa Voice Profile in my custom skill?

Alexa has ability to identify user by voice (but user need to create alexa voice profile (AVP) ) once AVP is created can I use it in my custom skills? I could not find any useful information/documentation/samples about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available but only as developer preview, for exclusive companies/users. More info: [link](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/09acb84e-6d56-463b-959c-9e15c3ed3893/announcing-more-personalized-skill-responses-when-alexa-recognizes-a-customer-s-voice-developer-preview). When it will be a available, they will probably announce it in their blog: [link](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/).

So short answer would be: they are working on it, but it is publicly not available.